# UIView subviews not appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with a `UIView`. Inside that `UIView` I add elements like a text label. When I run my code it is not there.

```
import UIKit

 class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController {

//variables that will hold data sent in through previous event controller
var eventImage = ""
var eventName = ""
var eventDescription = ""
var eventStreet = ""
var eventCity = ""
var eventState = ""
var eventZip = 0
var eventDate = ""
//
lazy var currentEventImage : UIImageView = {
    let currentEvent = UIImageView()
    let imageURL = URL(string: self.eventImage)
    currentEvent.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL!)
    currentEvent.clipsToBounds = true
    currentEvent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    currentEvent.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    currentEvent.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return currentEvent
}()
//will be responsible for creating the UIView that contains relevant event information
let eventInfoContainerView: UIView = {
   let infoContainer = UIView()
    infoContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    infoContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return infoContainer
}()

lazy var eventNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let currentEventName = UILabel()
    currentEventName.text = self.eventName
    currentEventName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return currentEventName
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.title = eventName
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "icons8-Back-64"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoBack))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    //Subviews will be added here
    view.addSubview(currentEventImage)
    view.addSubview(eventInfoContainerView)
    eventInfoContainerView.addSubview(eventNameLabel)
    //Constraints will be added here
    _ = currentEventImage.anchor(view.centerYAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -305, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: self.view.frame.width, heightConstant: 200)
    _ = eventInfoContainerView.anchor(currentEventImage.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
     _ = eventNameLabel.anchor(eventInfoContainerView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)



}

func GoBack(){
 _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 }
```

I am kind of lost I viewed a tutorial where they added elements to a `UIView` in a similar fashion and things appeared. Any insight would be helpful. Tried changing multiple things and nothing really made it appear and I have researched a couple answers I know it is probably something small that my eyes are just looking past but I can't discover it at this point.

This is my custom method for setting constraints

```
 import UIKit


extension UIView {

func anchorToTop(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

    anchorWithConstantsToTop(top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
}

func anchorWithConstantsToTop(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant).isActive = true
    }

}


func anchor(_ top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    if let top = top {
        anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant))
    }

    if let left = left {
        anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant))
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant))
    }

    if let right = right {
        anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant))
    }

    if widthConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
    }

    if heightConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
    }

    anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})

    return anchors
}

}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but, I find Xcode's View Debugging feature handy for this kind of thing.  Take a snapshot of the screen when it's showing something you don't expect.  Then you can look at the hierarchy, constraints, off-screen views and other clues.

Comment: I did the UIView is there but the label is not. When I check the variable in the textlabel it is stored there. But no appearance

Comment: @SJackson5 - you need to show your `.anchor(...)` function. We can't see what might be going on if we don't know what that function is doing.

Comment: You aren't setting the constraints properly, Are you sure this is compiling, because UIView has no method called `anchor`?

Comment: @Abizern that is my own custom method

Comment: Could you show what the custom methods are, because that seems to be where the problem is. It's hard to reproduce the problem otherwise.

Comment: @Abizern I added it

Comment: Error fixed I appreciate everyone's help and feed back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - now that we see your `.anchor(...)` function...

The TOP of your label is set to the BOTTOM of `eventInfoContainerView` with `topConstant: 20` ... which is ***+20***

Change that value to `-20` (assuming you want the label along the bottom of the view):

```
    _ = eventNameLabel.anchor(eventInfoContainerView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -20, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

<s>Assuming your `.anchor(...)` function / extension is working properly, I think the only thing wrong is that you forgot to set:</s>

```
infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

when you initialize your `eventInfoContainerView`

Comment: my custom method already handled this in my anchor function. See edits

Comment: still not there

Comment: an hour lost due to constraints is that something. I appreciate the help man honstly

Comment: however,  I had to set it to like -400 to get it in the right place any hints about why that is wrong?

Comment: i don't think it is being added to the uiview at all

Comment: see comments for additional thoughts

Comment: below the picture or ten pixels away from the top of the UIView

Comment: OK - you are adding the label as a subview of `eventInfoContainerView` ... if you want the label at the *top* of that view, then you need to constrain / anchor it to the `.topAnchor` of the view, and add `+10` ... right now, you have it constrained to `eventInfoContainerView.bottomAnchor`.

Comment: As a side note: you might think your UIView extension for setting anchors saves work, but... the way you're doing it seems like it can cause lots of confusion.